# Rails 3 can't perform validation for persited object when use collection_singular_ids=ids method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, model-associations

Is there any way to avoid automatically saving object while assigning collection attributes(collection_singular_ids=ids method)?

for example, I have the following Test and Package model, Package has many tests. User can build package bundle with number of tests.

```
# test.rb
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# package.rb
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :package_tests 
  has_many :tests, :through => :package_tests
  belongs_to :category

  validate :at_most_3_tests

  private
  # tests count will differ depends on category.
  def at_most_3_tests
    errors.add(:base, 'This package should have at most three tests') if  test_ids.count > 3
  end
end

# package_test.rb
class PackageTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
  belongs_to :test

  validates_associated :package
end
```

No issue on validation when package object is **new**.

```
1.9.2 :001> package = Package.new(:name => "sample", :cost => 3.3, :test_ids => [1,2,3,4])
=> #<Package id: nil, name: "sample", cost: 3.3> 
1.9.2 :002> package.test_ids
=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
1.9.2 :003> package.save
=> false 
1.9.2 :004> package.save!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: This package should have at most three tests
1.9.2: 005> package.test_ids = [1,2]
=> [1, 2] 
1.9.2 :005> package.save!
=> true
```

But I couldn't hit at_most_3_tests method with **persisted** package object.

Join table record is created immediately when assigning test ids

```
1.9.2: 006> package
=> #<Package id: 1, name: "sample", cost: 3.3> 
1.9.2: 007> package.test_ids
=> [1,2]
1.9.2: 007> package.test_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1,2,3,4,5]
1.9.2: 008> package.test_ids 
=> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Client requirement is drop-down interface for selection of multiple tests in package form
and also used [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) jquery plugin for drop-down. Rhmtl code looks like

```
<%= form_for @package do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <div> <label>Select Tests</label> </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.select "test_ids", options_for_select(@tests, f.object.test_ids), {}, { "data-validate" => true, :multiple => true} %>
  </div>
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For limit number of associations**

You can use the following validations as the following instead of your method:

```
has_many :tests, :length => { :maximum => 3 }
```

**For using Multiple select**

I have this issue before, and I solved it using the following code:

```
<%= f.select(:test_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(@tests, :id, :name,  @promotion.test_ids), {}, {multiple: true, "data-validate" => true}) =>
```

I think [options_from_collection_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select), read categories of post example from this [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) may help you.

**For Validation**

I used [validates_associated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated), as the following:

```
 validates_associated :tests
```

**For get the old attributes for persisted object**

You can use [reload](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reload) for active record as the following:

```
1.9.2: 006> package
=> #<Package id: 1, name: "sample", cost: 3.3> 
1.9.2: 007> package.test_ids
=> [1,2]
1.9.2: 007> package.test_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1,2,3,4,5]
1.9.2: 007> package.reload
=> #<Package id: 1, name: "sample", cost: 3.3> 
1.9.2: 008> package.test_ids 
=> [1,2]
```

Or you can check validation of package object, if it is false reload it:

```
unless package.valid?
  package.reload
end
```

Comment: I can't able to call package.valid? because whenever assigning array of ids then automatically save action is triggered. For example package.test_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: @ManivannanJeganathan I update my answer to use this validation `has_many :tests, :length => { :maximum => 3 }`

Comment: My validation is not only based on length. I just given example code. 
params[:package] should always have test_ids parameter like {:cost => 3.4, :test_ids => [1,2,3,4,5]}.
Simply I need to hit validation method in package model and render form if fails validation.
I can hit validation method with help of your answer by calling ```validates_associated :package``` in PackageTest model. But 
if validation fails related to test_ids validation, exception raised instead of returning true or false.
Ex code ```if @package.update_attributes params[:package] else render "form"```

Comment: I was trying ```validates_associated :package``` in ```PackageTest``` instead of ```validates_associated :tests``` in Package model.
it solved my problem. Thanks for help

Comment: When I calling test_ids in at_most_3_tests method always returns database results instead parameter values. How to retrieve values from memory?

Answer (score 3):

If you're manually assigning the test_ids in the controller, I'd suggest updating the entire object with nested attributes instead. This assumes that `params[:package][:test_ids]` is set to your list of test ids (which Mohamed's answer will help with).
So your controller action would look something like this:

```
def update
  package = Package.find(params[:id])
  package.update_attributes params[:package]
end
```

This will update everything at once in an ActiveRecord/database transaction. This means that if the validation fails, all of the changes will be rolled back, so it won't matter that the tests got saved. More information is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).

Also, I'd recommend calling `tests.size` instead of `test_ids.count`, since the replacement will tend to generate a better query (or not have to go to the database at all).

Comment: Fine.But there is problem when calling update_attributes with test_ids parameter, 
it will raise exception instead of returning true or false if validation fails related to test_ids validation(at_most_3_tests method). Any suggestion?
Example code: if package.update_attributes params[:package]

Comment: I used **validates_associated :package** in PackageTest model

Comment: validates_associated shouldn't raise an exception by default. What error are you getting?

Comment: ```Validation failed: Package is invalid``` because of parameter test_ids(#=> [1,2,3,4,5]) which is validated in ```Package``` model.

Comment: What if you use `validates_associated :tests` in your Package model instead? I'm not sure that having it in PackageTest would produce the desired result anyway. Also, are you sure you're not calling `update_attributes!` or `save!` anywhere? That would result in an exception for a validation error, which is not what you want in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Working as expected If I use ```validates_associated :tests``` in Package model.
But If I try ```validates_associated :package``` in ```PackageTest``` model will raise exception instead of returning true or false.
I am sure that I am not calling save! or update_attributes! anywhere. I have attached [demo](https://github.com/jmaniv/test_demo) project for your reference.